# Magento issue, "catalog_category_productsJsObject is not defined"

Tags: php, magento, referenceerror

I'm not really sure where to start with this issue. When I go to *Catalog -> Manage Categories* I get the following errors:

[image: Magento Error]

And I'm unable to click any of the categories- or subcategories- on the left hand side, the body of the page remains blank:

[image]

Sorry that I can't provide much more information other than that. I've tried looking at *app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml* and everything there looks right.

Any helpful thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: looks like some module broke js
try to disable modules one by one to find wich module affect this

Comment: Yes, you were on the right track.